# Combining asyncio with a multi-worker ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Is it possible to take a blocking function such as `work` and have it run concurrently in a `ProcessPoolExecutor` that has more than one worker?

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep, time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

num_jobs = 4
queue = asyncio.Queue()
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_jobs)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def work():
    sleep(1)

async def producer():
    for i in range(num_jobs):
        results = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, work)
        await queue.put(results)

async def consumer():
    completed = 0
    while completed < num_jobs:
        job = await queue.get()
        completed += 1

s = time()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(producer(), consumer()))
print("duration", time() - s)
```

Running the above on a machine with more than 4 cores takes ~4 seconds. How would you write `producer` such that the above example takes only ~1 second?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`await loop.run_in_executor(executor, work)` blocks the loop until `work` completes, as a result you only have one function running at a time.

To run jobs concurrently, you could use `asyncio.as_completed`:

```
async def producer():
    tasks = [loop.run_in_executor(executor, work) for _ in range(num_jobs)]
    for f in asyncio.as_completed(tasks, loop=loop):
        results = await f
        await queue.put(results)
```

Comment: Nice use of `as_completed`. In this variant I the OP doesn't even need a queue? The whole loop can be transferred to the `consumer`, which effectively picks up the items as they are finished. A queue still exists, but it's internal to the executor.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is in the `producer`. Instead of allowing the jobs to run in the background, it waits for each job to finish, thus serializing them. If you rewrite `producer` to look like this (and leave `consumer` unchanged), you get the expected 1s duration:

```
async def producer():
    for i in range(num_jobs):
        fut = loop.run_in_executor(executor, work)
        fut.add_done_callback(lambda f: queue.put_nowait(f.result()))
```